# Custom Data-bound control help

Tags: asp.net

I have never done this before and am very beginner in this one, so please treat me that way and help me. Obviously this is a complex topic for me at this stage.

I need to develop a custom data-bound control which will contain, few text-boxes, drop-down lists, labels, and other standard web-server controls. And, I want to be able to load this control from a web page on button click. When the user enters any data to any of its child controls, i should be able to save, and also retrieve when the data-bound control is loaded again. Also, the data in the child control should retain their value on postback.

Can someone help me getting into building this? What approach should i follow? Any books or artilces matching my requirement will be really helpful which i can read and help me develop this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a custom data bound control: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366540.aspx

Just out of curiosity, using a FormView or DetailsView control wouldn't solve the problem you are experiencing?  It has to be a custom control?